# Button com text Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile e queria deixar minha aplicação com essa aparência

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não estou conseguindo colocar o texto embaixo do botão e colocar uma cor de fundo cinza no botão porque já estou definindo o background-color do botão com uma imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio3.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RGM:XXXXX"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"

    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fulann"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="Principal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/auto"
        android:text="Auto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:background="@drawable/portateis"
        android:text="Portáteis" />


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não seria possível trabalhar com imageview já com as imagens de botões criados e aplicar o evento de clique nesses imageviews?
No meu projeto eu fiz assim(a combinação de cores está feia ainda, mas depois eu ajusto)

[image: Print]

Segue código:

Na activity da tela que você está criando, usa um código assim(adaptando para seus imageviews correspondentes a cada botão que precisa) para cada imageview:

Declara os objetos na classe principal, fora do oncreate:

```
   private ImageView btnImport;
```

Depois fará um código destes para cada imageview que precisará ser clicado:

```
btnImport = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnImportID);
btnImport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, LeitorActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Só lembrando que esse trecho de código meu, fará o carregamento de uma nova tela(intent) ao toque do usuário no imageview em questão.

Comment: como eu iria fazer isso ?